# Fiddler slows down my browsers

Tags: performance, fiddler

Working with fiddler on 2 pcs. On my better performing pc fiddler slows down both browsers (firefox and IE7) significantly.

any suggestions would be appreciated

thanks,
Ido

Comment: Just for the note: HTTP analyzer can slow down browsers significantly too, and it will regularly crash if it remains running too long in the background. So I guess each sniffer has its share of problems.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is just a function of what fiddler does.

Ultimately, Fiddler is a debugging tool and not something you should have running all the time. Debugging tools do generally cause the thing being debugged to run slower.

Comment: I've never seen any indication that this is true, and as Fiddler does not emit any server or script detectable tokens, I find it rather hard to believe.

Comment: @Eric Law: Indeed. I was incorrect so I have removed that sentence. It must have been some other debugging tool I was thinking of.

Comment: GMail does have a "you are on a slow connection" warning. Since you can instruct Fiddler to simulate a slow connection, maybe that's what you saw?

Answer (score 1):

"slow", without further data, isn't enough to go on. Have you looked at the requests (right-click, choose properties) to see which part of processing is the long-running part?

The most likely explanation is that on the PC which is operating slowly, when Fiddler isn't running, you have IE's Tools / Internet Options / Connections / LAN Settings / "Automatically detect proxy settings" checked. If you uncheck that box, you will likely find that throughput through Fiddler improves dramatically.

Of course, there's some overhead in running a buffering proxy; you can improve performance by enabling streaming mode (if you're not doing breakpoint debugging); see http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/streaming.asp

You can also help constrain the memory consumed by Fiddler using the Filter's tab; check the "Keep only the most recent [#] sessions" at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I'm looking at a way to provide this sort of tip inside Fiddler itself.

Comment: I'm not sure this fixed my issue but it's worth trying: if you browse the web regularly with Fiddler HTTPS Decrypt enabled, go to Tools > WinINET Settings > Content (tab) > SSL Certificates > Personal & delete all Fiddler certificates there. At some point the list is so huge it hurts performance, I've come to think.

Answer (score 0):

I've found Fiddler a little slow as well and I've switched to using [CharlesProxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) instead: however, if you always have them running and have them logging all browser interactions, then they will make your machine slower (as all browser requests all go through the Fiddler/Charles Proxy system and be logged and use up memory).

Comment: You can set Fiddler to only keep the most recent 200(?) sessions in memory (on the Filters tab). This keeps its memory usage in check.

Answer (score 0):

I haphazzardly installed Fiddler to try to fix something it wouldn't fix anyway.  Not only did I have to uninstall it to get my browser to operate correctly again, I had to remove its dangling registry keys.

Answer (score 0):

I found that Fiddler adds longer and longer delays as the session list grows. After I captured about 1/2 million sessions it was adding about 3 seconds to every request.

If this is your problem, just remove all the sessions from time to time, or set a filter to capture less traffic.

Comment: I discovered that there is also a drop down list on the toolbar to choose max sessions to keep.